# how to add number after each four lines

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, awk

i have a file which contain:

```
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccc
dddddddddd
eeeeeeeeee
ffffffffff
gggggggggg
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccc
dddddddddd
.....
```

and i want to add number for each four lines,like this result

```
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccc1
dddddddddd
eeeeeeeeee
ffffffffff
gggggggggg2
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccc3
dddddddddd
....
```

how to do that,
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '!(NR%4){sub(/$/,++x)}1' file
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccc1
dddddddddd
eeeeeeeeee
ffffffffff
gggggggggg2
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccc3
dddddddddd
```

Comment: Thanks .it do the job

Comment: You are on fire! Good one :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
$ awk 'NR%4==0 {$0=$0""++incr} 1' file
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccc1
dddddddddd
eeeeeeeeee
ffffffffff
gggggggggg2
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccc3
dddddddddd
```

#### Explanation

- `NR%4==0 {$0=$0""++incr}` if the number or record (of line, in this case) is 4k, then append the `incr` variable to the end of the line. Using `++incr` we make it be `1` the first time it is used.
- `1` performs the default `awk` behaviour: `{print $0}`.

Comment: +1 and I was about to say the `""` in `$0""++incr` isn't doing anything until I tried it with `$0` having a numeric value and discovered it actually is necessary to do that or `$0(++incr)`. I suppose it's because `$0++incr` could be interpreted as `$0 + (+incr)`

Comment: @fedorqui ,it has a bit wrong ,it marks the first line as 1 ,the fifth line as 2 ...but i need the fourth line as 1 and the eigth line as 2...

Comment: @EdMorton thanks! Yes, I tried with `$0++incr` and wasn't working, hence I added the `""` :)

Comment: @YOU yes, I did it wrong the first time. Then I noticed it is on the `4K` lines, not the `4K + 1` as I initially posted.